# Responsive div table without access to CSS sheet

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm using my work Drupal-based CMS, all I have access to is the Body WYSIWYG and Source editor. I can't access the CSS stylesheet at all.

I've created an HTML table, 3x3, each cell with an image and a caption. Works fine on desktop, but on mobile the table runs off-screen. [Here it is in place](https://www.hta.gov.uk/guidance-public/public-guides-codes-and-standards).

I'm trying to recreate the table with div tags instead, for responsiveness and accessibility for screen readers etc. Ideally, it would be great if the table reflowed to fit the screen, going from maybe 4 columns across on desktop to a single column on mobile. Ideally, the images would resize responsively, too.

[Here's what I've got so far](https://jsfiddle.net/768ga3va/) (jsfiddle). I'm truly amateur level so it's a mash of tutorials. It's functional, but seems to stick in one column even though there are row tags?

Can you help? Again, I can only edit body HTML, no CSS access.

*Ignore the below - necessary to post jsfiddle link.*

```
<div class="divTable" style="width: 100%;">
```

Comment: If you can edit the html part, then you might be able to insert CSS in between `<style>/* my CSS here that will overwrite previous external style sheet loaded in the <head> of that very document */</style>` tags . ;)

Answer (score 1):

This simplest thing you could do to make this work in to add the following inline style tag above your content:

```
<style>
    .divTableCell {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 24%;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
</style>
```

However, you'll find that this isn't very responsive on smaller screens.  I'd suggest looking into flex layout here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout

Keep in mind that as long as it's a web page, then you'd always have access to the CSS sources via the developer tools ([F12] key) of any modern browser.

Comment: I've given your first suggestion a go (I'll check out flex layout) -  it works really quite well, thank you. I've also played around with using % instead of px sizes for the images and that works well, too. Do you know how to make the tops of the cells align rather than the bottom?

Comment: Hopefully the edited answer does the trick.  Please accept this answer if that did work for you.